# Mi aplicacion en WPF consume muchos recursos

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un programa en WPF, pero veo que a veces inicia y consume 0.1% del procesador y al estar usándolo no hay problema, pero otras sin hacer nada consume 30% y no entiendo por que, pues es de vez en cuando no siempre y no hay nada en especial. Por ejemplo abro una ventana nueva y a veces va bien otras lento abriendo la misma ventana sin nada mas, mismo método, mismo uso pero a veces consume bastante.
Ojo que las demas aplicacion no importan, pues es en si la de Ciber que consume 30%
[image]

Comment: Pues hay que ver en qué condiciones ocurre, debes comprobar, y si es necesario, indicar si la carga aumenta al ejecutar algún algoritmo específico de tu aplicación u ocurre de la nada. Usas threads? Timers? Triggers? Bucles?

Comment: Uso una timer, de echo creo que es por que no uso hilos y al momento de cerrar el login y cargar el menu noto que sube bastante. Imagino cierra todo y carga el menu al mismo tiempo